# In SQL Server 2008, is possible to one database subscribe 2 publications for the same database? (merge replication)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I'm trying to set up an high availability architecture using merge replication.
I have 3 databases, and I'm trying to keep them all up to date with merge replication.

So far I've manage to create one publisher and 2 subscribers, and all works fine...except when the publisher goes down.

So I thought about creating one more publisher and make the other databases also subscribe to it. I can do the publication normally, but when I create the local subscription, even though the GUI says it went successfully, the new subscription does not appear under "Local Subscriptions" folder.

Is this possible? or is it a limitation of sql server? (if it is possible...what may be wrong in my setup?)

regards

Comment: Replication is not "high availability" as mentioned in answers to your previous question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7690/is-it-possible-to-have-2-or-more-databases-active-and-synchronized-between-them. And now you ask for help on the wrong solution?

Comment: is this case of replication it also works as high availability, because if one server fails, the other ones are available to do the exact same work. I just want to know if this is possible, or if theres is any limitation (like one table only can subscribe one subscription)

Comment: no, it isn't HA. It is replication. Do you publish the whole database?

Comment: @RagnaRock I feel like this is about the fourth time people have complained about your communication on this site. Is this something that we can help you resolve? If you do want help, please visit http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap and we can see what's going on.

Comment: this is replication, but replication can be used to achieve HA, as stated [here](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/whitepapers/archive/2009/09/23/using-replication-for-high-availability-and-disaster-recovery.aspx). At this point I'm just testing this technology, with 3 SQL instances with just one table for testing purposes. If it goes well I plan to replicate the whole DB.  
I want to know if its possible to have a circular chain of merge replication between the 3 DB's. If it is...I'm not being able to do it, but I'm not having any explicit error, it's just not working

Comment: That link is an edge case and doesn't match what you want. Don't pick one article that agrees with what you want: it differs from all the answers and advice given on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible.  Do not use SQL replication for high availability.  It is an exotic and soon-to-be deprecated feature set.

Comment: Brilliant. It's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

well, its actually possible but with [peer-to-peer replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196.aspx) too bad this is a enterprise edition feature only